# Geometrically showing $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} > \frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}$, for $0 < \beta < \alpha < 90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I attempting to prove the show trig identity, i.e. $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} > \frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}$. I have found that the radius is $1$ so there are three line segments equal to $1$, but I am unsure which segment would be $\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}$?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @robjohn I have identified the line segments equal to one and a few that are equal to $\sin\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$ (I now see this is difficult to explain without points on my diagram). My question is how to get the two sin over each other? I'm aware that tan is sin/cos but do not know how to approach sin/sin? Maybe a ratio?

Comment: As mentioned in the post on context I linked above, where this problem came from can be important. This is not a simple problem and the simplest approach I see so far is to use the identity $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac x{2^k}\right)$$ and then notice that $\cos(x)$ is a decreasing function on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: Also note that the inequality, as stated in the question, cannot be correct since taking the reciprocal of both sides gives $\frac\beta\alpha\lt\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)}$. You need the assumption shown in the image that $\beta\lt\alpha$.

Comment: Although I had come across it before, it had entirely slipped my mind that this inequality is associated with the name of [Aristarchus of Samos](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Aristarchus.html) (c.310-230 BC). A search including his name turns up this answer by @EuYu: [Proof of Aristarchus' Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538557/213690).

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin x < x < \tan x \qquad \forall~x \in [0, \frac{\pi}2]$$

If one agrees to start with the above known fact (which is purely an intuitive geometric fact as detail in e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99003/356647) and NOT about algebraic analysis of functions), then:

On one hand, we have 
$$ \frac{\alpha - \beta}2 > \sin \bigl( \frac{ \alpha -\beta}2\bigr) \quad \implies\quad \alpha - \beta > 2 \sin \bigl( \frac{ \alpha -\beta}2\bigr)  \tag*{Eq.(1)}$$
On the other hand, $ \alpha > \beta$ and cosine being a decreasing function yield
$$ \beta < \tan\beta = \frac{ \sin\beta }{ \cos\beta } < \frac{ \sin\beta }{ \cos\bigl( \frac{ \alpha + \beta}2 \bigr) } \quad \implies \quad \sin\beta > \beta \cdot \cos\bigl( \frac{ \alpha + \beta}2 \bigr)  \tag*{Eq.(2)}
$$
The product of the two inequalities (all terms are positive) gives us
\begin{align}
&& (\alpha - \beta) \cdot \sin\beta &> \beta \cdot 2 \sin\bigl( \frac{ \alpha - \beta}2 \bigr)\cos\bigl( \frac{ \alpha + \beta}2 \bigr) \\
&\implies & (\alpha - \beta) \cdot \sin\beta &> \beta \cdot (\sin\alpha - \sin\beta) \\
&\implies & \frac{\alpha - \beta}{ \beta } &> \frac{\sin\alpha - \sin\beta}{ \sin\beta}\qquad \text{, then $+1$ on both sides} \\
&\implies & \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } &> \frac{ \sin\alpha }{ \sin\beta}
\end{align}
Note that the whole derivation can be viewed as a purely geometric proof expressed via algebra. One can make a sketch and find **ALL** the relevant lengths (including e.g. $\frac{ \sin\beta }{ \cos( \frac{ \alpha + \beta}2 ) }$).

Answer (score 3):

Consider first the case where $\alpha, \beta$ are commensurable, i.e.:
$$
\alpha = n\gamma, \ \beta = m\gamma \quad (0 < m < n).
$$
By taking a smaller value of $\gamma$, if necessary, we can suppose
that $m > 1$.

Inscribe in the unit circle the broken line [polygonal chain]
with vertices:
$$
A_j = (\cos(j\gamma), \sin(j\gamma)) \quad (0 \leqslant j \leqslant n).
$$
Denoting the origin by $O$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{n}{m} =
& \frac{\text{area of polygon } OA_0A_1{\cdots}A_n}
{\text{area of polygon } OA_0A_1{\cdots}A_m}, \\
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta} =
& \frac{\text{area of triangle } OA_0A_n}
{\text{area of triangle } OA_0A_m}, \\
\therefore\ 
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta} < \frac{\alpha}{\beta}
\iff
& \frac{\text{area of triangle } OA_0A_n}
{\text{area of triangle } OA_0A_m}
< \frac{n}{m} \\
\iff
& \frac{\text{area of polygon } A_0A_1{\cdots}A_n}
{\text{area of polygon } A_0A_1{\cdots}A_m} 
> \frac{n}{m}.
\end{align*}
Define:
$$
a_j = \text{area of triangle } A_0A_jA_{j+1} \quad (0 < j < n).
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta} < \frac{\alpha}{\beta}
\iff
\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}}
{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{m-1}}
> \frac{n}{m}.
$$It is enough to prove that the sequence $(a_j)$ is strictly
increasing, because this implies:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}}
{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{m-1}}
& = 1 + \frac{a_m + a_{m+1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}}
{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{m-1}} \\
& \geqslant 1 + \frac{(n - m)a_m}{(m - 1)a_{m-1}}
> 1 + \frac{n - m}{m - 1}
= \frac{n - 1}{m - 1} \\
& > \frac{n}{m}.
\end{align*}
If $B_j$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $A_0$ to $A_{j+1}A_j$
produced, then $A_0B_{j+1}$ intersects $A_jB_j$ at a point $C$, and
$A_0B_{j+1} > AC > A_0B_j$, whence $a_{j+1} > a_j$, as required.
$\square$

This figure illustrates the case $n = 5$, $m = 3$, $j = 2$:

[image: An illustration of the case n = 5, m = 3, j = 2.]

If $\alpha, \beta$ are not commensurable, we can (as moderns!)
appeal to continuity, in order to complete the proof.  Although I
don't yet see how the ancient Greeks would have dealt with the
incommensurable case, I don't doubt that they did deal with it,
and probably with great ease.

(One might expect to find in
[Euclid](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html)
a proposition to the effect that if $m < n$, then the area of a
regular $m$-gon is less than that of a regular $n$-gon inscribed
in the same circle; but it doesn't seem to be there.
This may be worth a question in History of Science and Mathematics
SE - unless someone here already knows where such a result may be
found in extant Greek mathematical texts.)

Comment: @TangentPlane I'm getting a little frazzled, so will have to take some time to digest all this. Meanwhile, I have added a section about perimeters to my [question in HSM-SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7919). I apologise if it is essentially just a copy of something you've already written!

Comment: Alternatively, since the angles $\angle A_j A_0 A_{j+1}$ are all equal for $1\leq j < n,$ you can reflect $A_{j-1}$ over $A_0A_j$ onto $A_0 A_{j+1}$, and then $\triangle A_{j-1} A_0 A_j$ is congruent to a triangle that is strictly contained in $\triangle A_j A_0 A_{j+1}$.

Comment: @DavidK That's a lot neater. Thank you. (Incidentally, it looks as if a long comment thread has been deleted. I never did get to grips with all the implications of this question, or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972693), or several other related questions. A big tidying-up job is probably needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches

---

**Concavity of $\boldsymbol{\sin(x)}$**

If $f(x)$ is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable), then $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is a decreasing function of $x$ and a decreasing function of $y$.

$\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}
$$
is a decreasing function of $x$. Therefore, if $\beta\lt\alpha$, then
$$
\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\beta}\gt\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}\implies\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\gt\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)}
$$

---

**Sine Doubling and $\boldsymbol{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1}$**

Using $\cos(x/2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}$, induction gives
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{2^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)}
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=x$. Thus,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}x
$$
Since $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, we see that $\frac{\sin(x)}x$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$. Therefore, if $\beta\lt\alpha$, then
$$
\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\beta}\gt\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}\implies\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\gt\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)={x \over \sin x}$$

$$f'(x)={\sin x - x \cos x \over \sin^2x}={\tan x - x \over \sin^2x \cos x}$$

For $x\in(0, \pi/2)$, $\tan x>x$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)) so $f'(x)>0$ which means that the function $f(x)$ is monotoniously increasing.

So if $\alpha>\beta$:

$$f(\alpha)>f(\beta)$$

$${\alpha \over \sin \alpha}>{\beta \over \sin \beta}$$

$${\alpha \over \beta}>{\sin \alpha \over \sin \beta}$$